# Как сделать выделение строки в таблице, не меняя цвет самой строки?

Tags: css

Всем привет, возможно глупо сформулировал вопрос.
Не могу понять, как с помощью css (sass), сделать визуальное наведение мышки на строку.
Нашел разные способы с помощью hover, и так далее.
Но во всех реализациях, цвет строки при наведении кардинально изменяется. Мне нужно просто немного затемнить строку при наведении мышки, не меняя его оригинальный цвет. 
Тут хороший пример как это выглядит https://codepen.io/Meller008/pen/zYNVNJq?editors=101
На примере видно, что не зависимо от цвета фона ячейки, происходит небольшое затемнение, что не мешает различать оригинальный цвет.

```
<div id="q-app">
  <div class="q-pa-md">
    <q-markup-table>
      <template>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th class="text-left">Dessert (100g serving)</th>
            <th class="text-right">Calories</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
      </template>
      <template>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td class="text-left" style="background: #ff9797">Frozen Yogurt</td>
            <td class="text-right">159</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="text-left" style="background: #ff9797">Ice cream sandwich</td>
            <td class="text-right">237</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="text-left" style="background: #5e377b">Eclair</td>
            <td class="text-right">262</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="text-left" style="background: #5e377b">Cupcake</td>
            <td class="text-right">305</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="text-left">Gingerbread</td>
            <td class="text-right">356</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </template>
    </q-markup-table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В приведенном примере подсвечивание строки таблицы при наведении на нее реализовано с помощью добавления псевдоэлемента `::before` для каждой ячейки `td` таблицы, который показывается при наведении на строку `tr`. Ниже пример, который вам нужен, взял его оттуда как есть, ничего не меняя.

```css
table {border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 0; width: 100%; box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgb(0 0 0 / 20%), 0 2px 2px rgb(0 0 0 / 14%), 0 3px 1px -2px rgb(0 0 0 / 12%);}
thead {border-bottom: 1px solid black;}
td {border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1); padding: 10px 5px;}

/*Ниже то что вам нужно*/

table td {position: relative;}

td::before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.03);
}

tr:hover td::before {
    content: "";
}
```

```html
<table>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <td class="text-left" style="background: #ff9797">Frozen Yogurt</td>
    <td class="text-right">159</td>
  </tr>
</thead>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <td class="text-left" style="background: #ff9797">Ice cream sandwich</td>
    <td class="text-right">237</td>
  </tr>
</thead>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <td class="text-left" style="background: #5e377b">Eclair</td>
    <td class="text-right">262</td>
  </tr>
</thead>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <td class="text-left" style="background: #5e377b">Cupcake</td>
    <td class="text-right">305</td>
  </tr>
</thead>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <td class="text-left">Gingerbread</td>
    <td class="text-right">356</td>
  </tr>
</thead>
</table>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. А что заставляет появиться псевдо элемент ::before при наведении мышкой на строку?

Comment: Ага примерно понял! В понедельник протестирую на работе. Спасибо. Я никак не мог понять что происходит)

Comment: Это естественно) только я сначала попробую) а то вдруг вопросы появятся)

Comment: Работает четко!